# How to derive Hensel's lemma from the master factorisation theorem?

Tags: polynomials, p-adic-number-theory

In the book *p-adic Differential Equations* by **Kiran.S.Kedlaya** one finds the exercise II.(3):

> If $F$ is a complete nonarchimedean field, $P(X)\in\mathfrak o_F[X]$, and the reduction of $P(X)$ in $k_F$ factors as $\overline Q\cdot\overline R$, with $\overline Q$, $\overline R$ co-prime, then there exists a unique factorisation $P=QR$ in $\mathfrak o_F[X]$ with $Q,R$ lifting $\overline Q,\,\overline R$.

The hint says

> Since $\overline Q$, $\overline R$ are co-prime, there exist $\overline S, \overline T\in k_F[X]$ with $\overline Q\overline S+\overline R\overline T=1$, $\deg(\overline S)<\deg(\overline R)$ and $\deg(\overline T)<\deg(\overline Q)$. Use lifts of these to fulfill the conditions of the master factorisation theorem (stated at the end of the question).

**Attempt:**

We need to choose three elements $a,b,c\in\mathfrak o_F[X]$ and three complete additive subgroups $U,V,W$ satisfying the conditions. Since we want to factorise $P$, we shall choose $c=P$. Then choose arbitrary lifts $Q,R,S,T$ and let $a=Q$ and $b=R$. Since we shall have $ab-c\in W$, and we only know that $ab-c\in\left<p\right>$, we then choose $W=\left<p\right>\subseteq\mathfrak o_F[X]$.

Next let $U=\left<pT\right>$ and $V=\left<pS\right>$. As $QS+RT\equiv1\pmod p$, it follows that $f(u,v):=av+bu$ is a surjection from $U\times V$ to $W$.

It remains to show that there exists $\lambda>0$ such that $$\left|f(u,v)\right|\geq\lambda\cdot\text{max}\left\{\left|a\right|\left|v\right|,\left|b\right|\left|u\right|\right\}$$ and $$\left|ab-c\right|<\lambda^2\left|c\right|.$$

But I have no clue how to find such a $\lambda$, other than obviously that $\lambda\leq1$. And I do not see a way of applying the degree restrictions on $\overline Q$ and $\overline R$.

I have thought about varying the lifts $Q,R$ by some multiples of $p$ so that we can choose $\lambda=1$, but to no avail. And I have run out of ideas now.

---

**Master factorisation theorem:**

Let $R$ be a nonarchimedean ring. Suppose there are three elements $a,b,c\in R$ and three additive subgroups $U,V,W\subseteq R$ such that

1. The space $U,V$ are complete under the norm and $U\cdot V\subseteq W$.
2. The map $f(u,v):=av+bu$ is a surjection from $U\times V$ to $W$.
3. There exists $\lambda>0$ such that $$\left|f(u,v)\right|\geq\lambda\cdot\text{max}\left\{\left|a\right|\left|v\right|,\left|b\right|\left|u\right|\right\},\,\forall u\in U, v\in V.$$
4. We have $ab-c\in W$ and $\left|ab-c\right|<\lambda^2\left|c\right|$.

Then there exists a unique pair $(x,y)\in U\times V$ such that 
$$c=(a+x)(b+y),\quad\left|x\right|<\lambda\left|a\right|,\ \left|x\right|<\lambda\left|a\right|.$$
We also have
$$\left|x\right|\leq\lambda^{-1}\left|ab-c\right|\left|b\right|^{-1}\quad\left|y\right|\leq\lambda^{-1}\left|ab-c\right|\left|a\right|^{-1}.$$

---

Any help or reference is sincerely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to assume that $(p)$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathfrak{o}_F$. I mean for local fields whatever argument works with $p$ would also work with a uniformiser $\pi$, but could a "complete nonarchimedean field" also be something like $\Bbb C_p$, where the valuation is non-discrete?

Comment: I assume you work with $\lvert \sum a_ix^i \rvert := \max \lvert a_i \rvert$ on the polynomial ring, but notice that for any $0 < \rho< \infty$, $\max (\lvert a_i \rvert \cdot \rho^i)$ is also a norm and incorporates the degree. I am not sure, but maybe the right $\rho$ together with those so far unused degree restrictions would help to come up with an appropriate $\lambda$, for which I bet one should choose the lifts of $Q,R,S,T$ of the same degree as their reductions. I would also be surprised if we would not need $\deg(P) =\deg(\bar P) \ge 1$.

Comment: I forgot to mention, but I assumed to use $e^{-r}-$ Gauss norm for $r>0$ for some reason. I then realize that the condition $r>0$ is unnecessary, but I didn't come up with anything helpful yet.  Also, indeed I made an error about $(p)$ being the maximal ideal; I shall fix the question later. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: Please fix. I am interested in how this turns out.